# post on friends facebook wall

Tags: android, facebook

In my project I authenticate my Facebook account in the first activity and retrieved the friends id,name, birthday and pic, who is having birthday on the current day. I bundled them to the next activity and displayed the pic and name in listview. I want to post some message to their wall, when I click on the list. I used the following code to post on friends wall while click on the listview.

```
  public static String APP_ID = "my_app_id";
        public static Facebook authenticatedFacebook = new Facebook(APP_ID);
```

In my listview onclickitemlistner I used the following code. id_list is an ArrayList contains the ids of the friends.

```
try{
                        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                        JSONObject attachment = new JSONObject();

                        try {
                            attachment.put("message", "Many more returns of the day");


                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                        }
                        parameters.putString("attachment", attachment.toString());

                        parameters.putString("target_id", id_list.get(position)); 
                        parameters.putString("method", "stream.publish");
                        String  response = authenticatedFacebook.request(parameters);       
                        Log.v("response", response);
                    }
                    catch(Exception e){}
```

In my response I got invalid API key. But I used the correct key.

```
11-10 16:21:53.987: V/response(396): {"error_code":101,"error_msg":"Invalid API key","request_args":[{"key":"method","value":"stream.publish"},{"key":"attachment","value":"{\"message\":\"Many more returns of the day\"}"},{"key":"format","value":"json"},{"key":"target_id","value":"100000635832872"}]}
```

I used the same code to post using the retrieved id of the friend in my first activity where I authenticate my account. It works fine. But not works in the second activity where I display them in listview. I checked whether the session is valid or not. It results in invalid.

Comment: I think you friend did not allow app to comment on hi wall. Is't that?
Don't you remember when a dialog appear in FB to ask user if he allow the application to access data or not?

Comment: Then how to post on his wall. Suggest me how can I achieve this.

Comment: I tried the same code in the activity, where I used to  authenticate my account. It works fine, and the message get posted to my friend's wall. I think the problem is with the session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it work. Just change the Facebook.java class. Changed DEFAULT_AUTH_ACTIVITY_CODE to FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH. And check for Facebook session. It works fine with my code.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a user access token? I don't see any indication that you have an authenticated user available when you're making that request

Comment: Actually I have authenticated my facebook account in the first activity and retrieved the friends ids, picture, birthday. Checked if any friends have birthday on current date. If so, bundled the details of that friend to another activity, where i list them in a listview.

Comment: Do you have the publish_stream permission from that user? the error message usually means there's a malformed access token or something like that

Comment: I added public_stream in permissions[] in the activity, which authenticate my account.

Comment: I tried the same code in the activity, where I used to  authenticate my account. It works fine, and the message get posted to my friend's wall. I think the problem is with the session.

Comment: My Facebook session get expired.